Probability - Findind Expectation of $ Y$ ~ Uni{0, ... 10} given $X \sim Geo(1/2)$
Assume that each day, T diamonds are discovered, independently from previous days, with $ T \sim Geom(1/2) $. At the end of the day, those diamonds are taken to evaluation, and given a ranking that's distributed Uniformly {0, 1, ..10}. Again, each evaluation is ind. from the previous days.
I'm asked to find:
A) Expectation number of days passed until we find at least one diamond that is of ranking 10.
B) Given today 4 diamonds were discovered, the expected number of diamonds with ranking of 5 and above.
The answers are $ 6, 24/11, $ respectively.
I don't understand how to solve this.
So for day i, then the number of diamonds discovered is $X_i \sim Geom(1/2)$ and the evaluation for the diamonds having 10 ranking, given $X_i$, is $ Y_i \sim Bin(X_i, 1/10) $.
Could I get hints/partial answers on how to solve this? I'd appreciate it..

For a particular $i$-th day, you already know the marginal distribution of $X_i$ and the conditional distribution of $Y_i|X_i = x_i$. Then you can use the law of total probability to get the probability of $Y_i = 0$ by summation. This gives you the probability that not finding a rank 10 diamond in a day. Then you may use similar argue that the number of days of getting the first rank 10 diamond is having a geometric distribution and hence you know how to compute the expectation.

Hi, thanks for answering. I'm not sure I understood.
So $ P(Y_i = 0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(Y_i  = 0| X_i = n) $, which gives $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1/10)^n}{1/2^n}$, because$  X_i $ is geometric, and the conditional probability is $ X_i $ fails in a row. Then I get that $P(Y_i = 0) = 1/4 $.
Could you elaborate on how the number of days of getting the ranking 10 is a geometric distribution?

Your summand is the product of the conditional probabilities with the marginal probability $\Pr{X_i = n}$. I am not sure about your summand is correct - you should have $9/10$ in there somehow instead of $1/10$. Since each day is independent, you have an identical independent Bernoulli trials of getting a ranking 10 diamond. The number of trials of getting the first success hence follows a geometric distribution.
